# jQuery animate linear backwards

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm animating color change (using jquery.colors.js plugin)

I use animate function:

```
el.animate({"background-color": activeColor}, 1000, "linear");
```

this changes color (fade in or fade out depending on current and target colors). And the direction of the change is **from left to right.**

I need from **right to left**.

Any suggestions? Maybe to use some other easing from jquery ui?

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick for you:

```
var oldColor = el.css('background-color');

el.css('background-color', activeColor);
el.animate({"background-color": oldColor}, 1000, "linear");
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. but NO =) that is actually ends up with the oldColor but I need to END UP with the activeColor (actually its "transparent" - so the background should become transparent, but I want it to fade away from right to left, not form left to right as with "linear").

Comment: Lets say there was a rad back ground. I want to make it transparent with animate. So I use el. animate({'background-color': 'transparent'}, 1000, "linear") - It starts to become less red first from the left side (border). So during the animation the more pixels of the background are left the less them are red. Ok?

Comment: But your whole background is animating. I'm not seeing where this direction is coming into play.

Comment: Visually it  disappears (fading away) from left to right smoothly.